# how do i mask labeled object based on some specified threshold value for each objects area,majoraxis and minoraxis?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

i am currently using `bwconnomp` to label each connected object and `regionprops`to find area, majoraxis, minoraxis of each labeled object respectively. i am also displaying each labeled object its area,majoraxis and minoraxis. now i want to set some threshold for area,majoraxis and minoraxis and if the value of area,majoraxis and minoraxis is above specified threshold then that object has to be masked.how this can be done??

here is my code

```
clc
clear all
close all
Index = 1;
scrsz = get(0,'ScreenSize');
%read an image
while Index ~= 0
    % Open a dialog and select an image file
    [FileName,FilePath,Index] = uigetfile('*.png', 'Open Imagefile ');
    if Index == 0
        disp('Procedure Done')
        break;
    end
inimage = imread([num2str(FilePath) FileName]);
D=inimage;
A=inimage;
subplot(2,3,1);
imshow(inimage);
title('original image');


%labeling algorithm
 B=im2bw(inimage);
 C=imfill(B,'holes');
 label=bwlabel(C);
 max(max(label))
 CC = bwconncomp(B);
data = regionprops(CC,'all');


for j=1:max(max(label))
[row, col] = find(label==j);
len=max(row)-min(row)+2;
breadth=max(col)-min(col)+2;
target=uint8(zeros([len breadth] ));
sy=min(col)-1;
sx=min(row)-1;

for i=1:size(row,1)
x=row(i,1)-sx;
y=col(i,1)-sy;
target(x,y)=A(row(i,1),col(i,1));
end
mytitle=strcat('Object Number:' ,num2str(j),'area:', num2str(data(j).Area),'MajorAxis: ',num2str(data(j).MajorAxisLength),'MinorAxis: ',num2str(data(j).MinorAxisLength));
figure,imshow(target);title(mytitle);
a=size(target);
ax=a(1);
ay=a(2);
pos=[1,1,ay,ax];
rectangle('Position',pos,'EdgeColo','r')
end

next = input('next image? press Enter: ');
if next == 0
    channelactivity = 0;
    break
else
    close all
    disp('==================================')
    pause(0.2)
    continue
end

end
```

Comment: So are you saying that you only want to display the object if it surpasses a threshold for area, major axis and minor axis length?

Comment: @rayryeng no i just want to display objects which are below some specified threshold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it. The code is commented so easy to follow; the important line is the following:

```
AboveAreaIndices = find(vertcat(data.Area) > SomeValue)
```

In which you store the indices of the objects whose area is larger than `SomeValue`. In the example I color them red but you can do whatever you want with them or remove them altogether from the `data` structure.

You can also use logical operators to combine multiple conditions for example using the `MinorAxis` and `MajorAxis` properties. Note that I used `AllArea` as anew variable to store the concatenated areas to make things clearer, but you can keep them as `vertcat(data.Area)`.

```
AboveIndices = find(vertcat(data.Area) > SomeValue & vertcat(data. MinorAxis) > SomeValue & Bla bla bla...);
```

Whole code:

```
clear
clc
close all

%// Read and clean up sample image
A = imread('rice.png');

A = im2bw(A,.5);

A = bwareaopen(A,50);
CC = bwconncomp(A);

%// Same as you.
data = regionprops(CC,'all');

%// Concatenate all the areas into an array. 
AllArea = vertcat(data.Area);

%//========================================
%//==== Apply threshold on area here \\====

AboveAreaIndices = find(AllArea > 150);

%// If you wish to remove the entries from the data structure
% data(AllArea>150) = [];
%//========================================

%// Same for centroids...for display purposes
AllCentroids = vertcat(data.Centroid);


%// Display original and thresholded objects. Use the indices calculated
%// above to "mask" large areas if you want
imshow(A);

hold on

scatter(AllCentroids(:,1),AllCentroids(:,2),40,'b','filled')
scatter(AllCentroids(AboveAreaIndices,1),AllCentroids(AboveAreaIndices,2),40,'r','filled')
```

And sample output:

[image]

Comment: i tried masking in this way   AboveIndices = BW2(vertcat(data.Area) > 13000 & vertcat(data.MajorAxisLength) >300 & vertcat(data.MinorAxisLength) >90);
C = num2cell(AboveIndices)
BW2(vertcat((C{cellfun(@numel,C)})))=0; but its not working...